# How to include origin and destination UI window - Google Maps app

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am developing an application for Android. I'm using **`Google Maps`**.
But I have a doubt.
I have the address, latitude and longitude of the place.
From the user, I get only latitude and longitude values.

I already have [the map and the route line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAK34.png), but I **want to add the part regarding the user's input specifying the origin point of the route and the destination**, such as the [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYbFN.jpg).

Is it possible to add this part? If so, which kind of Google API service should I use?

Comment: I sincerely think the question is focused. The issue is only one and well specified by the questioner. Just my oppinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the [**Directions**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview) api for that.

> The Google Directions API is a service that calculates directions
> between locations using an HTTP request. You can search for directions
> for several modes of transportation, include transit, driving,
> walking, or cycling. Directions may specify origins, destinations, and
> waypoints, either as text strings (e.g. "Chicago, IL" or "Darwin, NT,
> Australia") or as latitude/longitude coordinates. The Directions API
> can return multi-part directions using a series of waypoints.

Take a look at its source code here [`DirectionsApi.java`](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/maps/DirectionsApi.java).

In order to add the UI (or at least something similar), check out the [**Api Picker**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker)

Two interesting options there:

- **Draw a route on a map**.
- **Get directions data**

I think here you'll find some examples of what you need:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-started#directions

Good luck and may the force be with you = )